# Touches method in UIViewController and UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawing, touches, touchesmoved

I'm working on iPad app. My `UIViewController` contains only a custom `UIView` with a size of 500wx500h.

I implemented the touches methods both in the `UIViewController` and the custom `UIView` in order to call the `UIViewController` touches methods when we touch all around the custom `UIView` and call the custom `UIView` touches methods when we touch inside it.

UIViewController touchesMoved :

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    NSLog(@"TEST"); // Added during edition
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(self.drawingView.frame, point)) {
        NSLog(@"UIVIEWCONTROLLER");
    }
```

}

Custom UIView touches Moved :

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"CUSTOM VIEW");
}
```

When I'm touching the custom `UIView` moving my finger, `CUSTOM VIEW` is logged until I removed the finger on the screen. On the other hand, when I'm touching outside of the custom UIView, the `UIVIEWCONTROLLER` is called only one time in the touchesMoved method.

Am I missing something wrong ?

**EDIT :** I added a log in my UIViewController touchesMoved method. When I touch inside the custom view, it logs the TEST during all the touching phase. But when I touch outside, I get the same behaviour.

Comment: what is `drawingView`? you said that your controller has just got one view, but it should have at least two: `self.view` and `drawingView`... could it be the former is hijacking the touches?

Comment: My UIViewController contains his own view and an other custom UIView (which is called drawingView).

Answer (score 0):

add exclusiveTouch property to your view to disable multi touches

```
your view.exclusiveTouch=YES;
```

Comment: I try to set it on the custom view firstly and on the uiviewcontroller view then but both don't work :/

Answer (score 0):

There is some likeliness that your self.view is intercepting touches and handling them, so they will not make it through to the view controller. You could try doing either of 2 things (or both) and see if it works:

1. `self.view.exclusiveTouch = NO;`
2. `self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;`

I would also try to call `[super touchesMoved: touches withEvent: event];`

Hope it helps.

Comment: `self.view.exclusiveTouch = NO;` had no effect. But `self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;` improved a bit the bahaviour. Instead of getting one `UIViewController` log, I get 7 `UIViewController`. The touches methods seems to be called only 7 times and stop to be called then.

Comment: Do you understand why ? :/

Comment: as I said, there is some view intercepting the touches. I think you should also try and call `super` implementation of `touchesMoved`... maybe not calling it may make the touch "die" in the controller code after some time.

Comment: btw, you don´t explain what you are trying to achieve... maybe be there are better and easier approaches to that...